# Why does R Startup Sequence still look "C:\Users\USER_NAME\Documents" for .RData when I have defined new R_HOME and HOME?

Tags: r

If `R_HOME` and `HOME` are not specified, R looks in "C:/Users/USER_NAME/Documents" and loads .RData on start up if it exists. It also saves the workspace there on exit if user clicks OK.

I set `R_HOME` and `HOME` environment variables to "C:/Users/USER_NAME/Documents/R" and it ALMOST works!

On exit, it saves .RData in the new path. But on start up it still looks back in Documents and will only load if .RData exists there.

I want it to restore the previous image just like the default setup, but from my new folder. I did a workaround to make this happen, but still don't understand why R uses my new folder to save on exit but NOT for loading on startup.

The help states:

```
> R then loads a saved image of the user workspace from ‘.RData’ in the
> current directory if there is one (unless --no-restore-data or
> --no-restore was specified on the command line).
```

I know that my changes have taken effect because I check it:

```
> Sys.getenv("HOME") --> 
[1] "C:/Users/Mike/Documents/R"

> Sys.getenv("R_USER") --> 
[1] "C:/Users/Mike/Documents/R"

> getwd() --> 
[1] "C:/Users/Mike/Documents/R"
```

Comment: Have you tried using a different RStudio project? Projects encapsulate a lot of this stuff for you so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: I am using RGui.